# Elasticsearch: date_histogram with 5y interval

Tags: elasticsearch

How to make Elasticsearch date_histogram work like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "age_range": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "birthdate",
        "interval": "5y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8939) in elasticsearch, you can use either 260 weeks(260w) or 1825 days(1825d) (you can consider leap year if you want).

This will work

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "birthdate",
        "interval": "1825d"

      }
    }
  }
}
```